# Add Base Path to an API in dotnet 6

Tags: c#, .net, api, .net-core

Need to remove the prefix from the API request

Current api path :
https://localhost:7131/api/server/controller/test-api

I need to trim /api/server/ from API request before forwarding it to the specified controller.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Please edit your question to include related code and tell us what the problem you're trying to solve is.

Comment: I need to forward api/server/controller/test-api to controller/test-api, where api/server is working as the base path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But if you want to forward *api/server/controller/test-api* to *controller/test-api*، You can use `[Route()]` in your controler

```
[Route("/api/server/[controller]")]
public class myController : Controller
{
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet("test_api")]
    public IEnumerable<> test_api()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

now if you call `https://localhost:7131/api/server/{yourContoroler}/test-api` your test_api is called. So you can choose to be `/api/server` or not